# Boost.Test - How to write a test that doesn't run automatically

Tags: c++, boost-test

A project I am working on uses continuous integration (CI) system that automatically builds and runs all test suites. Auto tests are run without any command line arguments. I would like to add long running tests into existing suites and I don't want those test to be trigger by CI. What is the proper way to add tests that don't run automatically?

I am thinking to use [custom command line arguments](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/custom_command_line_arguments.html). Is there more explicit way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Enabling or disabling test unit execution](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/enabling.html).

Essentially,

```
  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1, * boost::unit_test::disabled())
  {
     ...
  }
```

If you run without parameters, it will not execute.

With `--run_test=test1` or `--run_test=*`, it still will execute.